# Finding changepoints in a GAM?

Tags: confidence-interval, simulation, generalized-additive-model, change-point, credible-interval

I'm using generalized additive modeling to investigate the relationship between two variables, X and Y. I want to find changepoints--i.e., X values at which the slope changes direction. I can get point estimates from the fitted model, but the shape of the function and the number of inflection points aren't consistent across posterior simulations--so it doesn't seem straightforward to develop Bayesian credible intervals.

I know how to get confidence intervals for the slopes and identify periods where the slopes are significant. Am I limited to saying "Direction changes may occur within intervals in X where the slope is not significantly different from zero"? What other statements can I make about changepoints or shapes of the functions?

Minimal example of what I'm talking about with the different numbers of inflection points is below. (My actual data are messier and there's a lot more variability in shapes.)

Generate data and estimate model.

```
library(mgcv)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2) ## simulate data
dat <- gamSim(1, n=400, dist="normal", scale=2)
b <- gam(y~s(x2), data=dat)
```

Get predicted values and derivatives

```
x2  <- with(dat, seq(min(x2), max(x2), length.out = 500))
eps <- 0.0000001
lp0 <- predict(b, data.frame(x2), type = "lpmatrix")
lp1 <- predict(b, data.frame(x2 = x2 - eps), type = "lpmatrix")

pred <- lp0 %*% coef(b)
d1 <- ((lp1 - lp0) / eps) %*% coef(b)
```

Get changepoints (i.e., slope passes through zero)

```
find_changepoints <- function(x) {
    zeros <- lapply(2:length(x), function(r) {
        sign(x[r-1]) != sign(x[r])
        })
    
    c(0, as.numeric(unlist(zeros)))
}

change <- find_changepoints(d1)
```

Plot smooth with changepoints marked

```
results <- data.frame(x2, pred, d1, change) 

results %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x2, pred)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(data = . %>%  filter(change == 1))
```

[image: fitted smooth with changepoints marked]

Simulate smooths and slopes from posterior distribution and find changepoints for each rep.

```
nreps <- 50
set.seed(150)
b_sim <- rmvn(n  = nreps, mu = coef(b), V  = vcov(b))
sim_pred <- lp0 %*% t(b_sim)
sim_d1 <- ((lp1 - lp0) / eps) %*% t(b_sim)

sim_change <- apply(sim_d1, 2, find_changepoints)
```

Plot smooths with changepoints marked. Panel by number of changepoints detected in a rep.

```
sim_result <- data.frame(
    rep   = sort(rep(1:nreps, length(x2))),
    x2    = rep(x2, nreps),
    pred   = matrix(sim_pred, ncol = 1),
    d1     = matrix(sim_d1, ncol = 1),
    change = matrix(sim_change, ncol = 1)
    ) %>% 
    group_by(rep) %>% 
    mutate(nchange = sum(change)) %>% 
    group_by(rep, change) %>% 
    mutate(change_order = rank(x2))

sim_result %>% 
    ggplot(aes(
        x      = x2, 
        y      = pred, 
        group  = rep, 
        col    = factor(change_order))) +
    geom_line(alpha = 0.5, color = "gray") +
    geom_point(data = . %>%  filter(change == 1)) +
    facet_wrap(. ~ nchange) +
    labs(col = "Changepoint Index") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: Simulated smooths with changepoints marked, paneled by count of changepoints over the function]

Comment: From the question it looks like you are wanting to estimate inflection points in the GAM estimate rather than identify changepoints (which are statistically a completely different thing).  You may have more luck searching for inflection points.  Chanepoints identify a different statistical distribution prior to and after the change, it would be an alternative modelling approach to using a GAM.